# ArrayList is picking randomly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

everyone, I'm just a beginner so please be patient ;)
I have an ArrayList and it's picked randomly to my cardView, what should I change if I want pick it one by one in order?

```
 public static class Questions {
        private String mQuestion;
        private String mAnswer;


        // statyczne tablice, na podstawie których zostaną uzupełnione obiekty artykułów
        private static String[] sQuestions = {"1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                "2 Etiam sit", "3 Cras vel lorem",
                "Cras suscipit, urna at aliquam rhoncus",
                "Phasellus congue lacus eget neque",
                "Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam"};


        private static String[] sAnswers = {"1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam.",
                "2 Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis, turpis vel hendrerit interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci",
                "3 Nam congue, pede vitae dapibus aliquet, elit magna vulputate arcu, vel tempus metus leo non est. Etiam sit amet lectus quis est congue mollis.",
                "Phasellus congue lacus eget neque. Phasellus ornare, ante vitae consectetuer consequat, purus sapien ultricies dolor, et mollis pede metus eget nisi.",
                "Praesent sodales velit quis augue. Cras suscipit, urna at aliquam rhoncus, urna quam viverra nisi, in interdum massa nibh nec erat."};

        public Questions() {
            Random arry = new Random();

            mQuestion = sQuestions[arry.nextInt(sQuestions.length)];
            mAnswer = sAnswers[arry.nextInt(sAnswers.length)];
        }

        public String getTitle() {

            return mQuestion;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return mAnswer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are using Random to get the int for accessing the array. Obviously it will give random items.

Answer (score 1):

These lines need to be changed to point to desired indexes.

```
 mQuestion = sQuestions[arry.nextInt(sQuestions.length)];
 mAnswer = sAnswers[arry.nextInt(sAnswers.length)];
```

For example, if you wanted the question and answer at 5 then you would need to write

```
mQuestion = sQuestions[4];
mAnswer = sAnswers[4];
```

How you get the number (4 in my example) is your choice. A for loop or a while loop with incrementation will work. Passing direct numbers from keyboard input would also work.

Comment: You mean index 4 of the array not 5. 5 is out of bounds.

Comment: I meant to provide an example. In fact, I didn't notice that he only had 5 total questions. I'll amend my answer. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

Your array returns randomly because you have written it in this way.
First, take a look at your code

```
        Random arry = new Random();
        mQuestion = sQuestions[arry.nextInt(sQuestions.length)];
        mAnswer = sAnswers[arry.nextInt(sAnswers.length)];
```

You are taking a random element of your arrays because of the random function.
What you need to do is to replace the index part aka this one `[arry.nextInt(sQuestions.length)]`with the index of the element you want. If you want the first -> 0, 2nd -> 1 and so on. Don't go over arr.length-1 or an exception will be thrown.

All in all, put the indexes of the items you want to get like this,for example.:

```
    mQuestion = sQuestions[0];
    mAnswer = sAnswers[0];
```

The getters will give you "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" and "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam."

Make counters, create your own logic for how to return elements when the functions are called.

Comment: Thank You but how can I do this automatically like 1 and 1 then 2 and 2, 3 and 3 etc. ?  Smth like that http://imgur.com/a/2sRHX
something like a loop

Comment: `getTitle(){
    if(counter == 5){
        counter = 0;
     }
     temp = counter;
     counter++;
     return array[counter];
}`

And you create one more counter for the other getter. This will do it. Hope this helps

Comment: `mQuestion = sQuestions[counter];
 return mQuestion;` 
And you use the logic i wrote you in the previous comment for the counter.
It will work

Comment: Thanks for answer, atm I'm trying do this what u said but doesn't work for me, probably I'm doing smth wrong but ill try to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean?

```
int a=0;
while (a<arry.length)
{
        mQuestion = sQuestions[a];
        mAnswer = sAnswers[a];
   a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through an array in order you can do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    String s = array[i];
    // Do what you want with your string s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a global variable as the max value of the array?  then you can iterate it everytime Questions is called.

```
if(questionPlace < max){
 //assign values, questionPlace++;
}else{
 questionPlace = 0;
 //assign values
}
```